# svn: Can't connect to host Connection refused

Tags: centos, svn, ffmpeg

I'm trying to instal FFMPEG to my server but the command

```
svn checkout svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
```

Returns

```
svn: Can't connect to host 'svn.mplayerhq.hu': Connection refused
```

I can normally PING svn.mplayerhq.hu and disabling the firewall didn't work.

What can I do?

Thank you guys

Comment: Works OK for me. Have you got an edge firewall blocking it?

Comment: I woldn't know, Ben, but I guess not

Comment: Have you tried replacing "svn://" by "http://" or "https://". "git://" / "svn://" might be blocked at several places.

Answer (score 2):

a "Connection refused" simply means that you attempted to connect doing everything correctly, and for whatever reason, the remote host responded with a TCP Reject packet.  As to why they might have rejected your connection, I can only guess.  There may have been a device somewhere in the middle that might have also rejected the connection (a firewall someplace... or content-filtering service... or several other possibilities)

As it is a fairly public resource, I doubt it has anything to do with their network blocking your connection.  Perhaps your ISP doesn't allow connections to SVN (port 3690)... or the place you are connecting from limits connectivity for security reasons...

Comment: PORT 3690 is open and there's no firewall. Also, if it was the ISP I wouldn't be able to PING it, or would I?

Comment: PING uses an ICMP packet... svn uses TCP.   Big difference.  And yes, you can block one without the other.

Comment: I see. I've to find out what's wrong. My dedicated charges US$75 for each hour of support :(

Comment: Try using "telnet" to port 3690.  (telnet svn.mplayerhq.hu 3690)  If you are able to connect and able to see "( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops dept
h log-revprops partial-replay ) ) ) "  It's not the ISP or any blocking service in the middle, but rather something else wrong with your svn client.  Otherwise, it's *something* between your machine and svn.mplayerhq.hu.   Most likely, is *YOUR* firewall or *YOUR* ISP.  Without being on-site I honestly couldn't begin to tell you everything you need to check in order to rule out one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is actually working for me..

```
svn checkout svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
 U   ffmpeg
Checked out revision 26402.
```

Your client is unable to connect as that particular port is being blocked either on the server itself or on the actual client.

To check your client's firewall type the following command in terminal....

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

Otherwise you need to contact the network admin on the network that your client resides on to see if he can open up the outbound port for you.